# Do Loop for Coalesce SAS SQL for TWO left join

Tags: sas

I have this code in this code there are many repeating of Coalesce function I want to it in DO loop

```
proc sql;               
create table Policy_details as              
select t1.* ,   COALESCE(t2.NOOF_MEMBERS_INSURED, t3.NOOF_MEMBERS_INSURED) as NOOF_MEMBERS_INSURED ,                
    COALESCE(t2.Txt_Product_Type, t3.Txt_Product_Type) as Txt_Product_Type ,
    COALESCE(t2.Txt_Type_of_Policy, t3.Txt_Type_of_Policy) as Txt_Type_of_Policy ,
    COALESCE(t2.Boo_Type_of_Premium, t3.Boo_Type_of_Premium) as Boo_Type_of_Premium , 
        COALESCE(t2.DATE_COMMENCEMENT, t3.DATE_COMMENCEMENT) as DATE_COMMENCEMENT               
                
from Policy as t1               
left join apr_to_dec_15a_22 as t2 on t1.Txt_Policy_Number = t2.Txt_Policy_Number                
left join a15a_apr21_to_mar22 as t3 on t1.Txt_Policy_Number = t3.Txt_Policy_Number              
;               
quit;
```

I have this code in this code there are many repeating of Coalesce function I want to it in DO loop

Comment: What is it that is repeating? You seem to be coalescing 5 DIFFERENT sets of variables.  Are you asking how to generate code?

Comment: Looks more like you are updating the data from Policy with the data from apr_to_dec_15a_22  and a15a_apr21_to_mar22 .  Why not just just a DATA step with the UPDATE statement instead of SET or MERGE?

Comment: SQL does not have a DO loop or arrays.  Do you want to specify the different variables being coalesced, or do you want to do all of them automatically without knowing the variable names beforehand? Per @Tom UPDATE is the proper approach, and in certain scenarios the MODIFY statement would be used to update in place.

Comment: Actually i have lot's of Variables and i want just short code while using Loop For Coalesce and I dont wanna merge data set because in variables there are missing values

Comment: I need coalesce in Loop whether it is Proc SQL or SAS